# Error while sending List data to cloud firestore using REST api in flutter

Tags: firebase, rest, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I'm not able to send List of string to cloud firestore using REST api in flutter.

```
//###### here is my code ##########

Future<bool> addVisit(Visit visit) async { //function
try {
var response = await http.post( //post method to send data
  "${VISIT_API}",
  headers:
      {"Authorization": "Bearer ${Utils.loginToken}"},
```

Working fine upto "Facility", but getting error while inserting "Facility: as all others are String values and Facility is of type List

```
  body: json.encode(
    {
      "fields": {
        "status": {"stringValue": visit.status},
        "id": {"stringValue": visit.id},
        "name": {"stringValue": visit.name},
        "dateTime": {"integerValue": visit.dateTime},
        "mob": {"integerValue": visit.mob},
        "idproof": {"integerValue": visit.idproof},
        "address": {"stringValue": visit.address},
        "purpose ": {"stringValue": visit.purpose},
        "facility": {"arrayValue": visit.facility} //error line
      }
    },
  ),
);
print("reach");
if (response.statusCode == 200) { // successful
  print("visit added");
  return true;
} else {
  print(response.body);
}
} catch (err) {
throw err;
}
}
```

I do  the post-request like

```
 String VISIT_API =
 "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<database-id>/databases/(default)/documents/visits";
```

Error message is here

```
//###### Error Message #########
I/flutter (26972): {     //console output
I/flutter (26972):   "error": {
I/flutter (26972):     "code": 400,
I/flutter (26972):     "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"arrayValue\" at 
'document.fields[8].value': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.",
I/flutter (26972):     "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
I/flutter (26972):     "details": [
I/flutter (26972):       {
I/flutter (26972):         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
I/flutter (26972):         "fieldViolations": [
I/flutter (26972):           {
I/flutter (26972):             "field": "document.fields[8].value",
I/flutter (26972):             "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name 
\"arrayValue\" at 'document.fields[8].value': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list."  
I/flutter (26972):           }
I/flutter (26972):         ]
I/flutter (26972):       }
I/flutter (26972):     ]
I/flutter (26972):   }
I/flutter (26972): }

//#################################

//visit.facility contains :
//["lunch" , "dinner"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try writing your `facility` array value like this:

```
"facility": {
  "arrayValue": {
    "values": [
      {
        "stringValue": "lunch"
      },
      {
        "stringValue": "dinner"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The `"values"` part comes from the references for [Value](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/Value) and [arrayValue](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/ArrayValue).

Comment: Thanks @Juan Laara..It work fine when we add of single array element ony by one manually. But still facing the same problem when I assign list object

Comment: Updated answer. You'll need to take the values out of `visit.facility` and put them into the format above.

Comment: Thanks @Juan Lara. The issue is fixed now. Can you pls share me the syntax for inserting **mapValue** . I have tried with this [link](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/Value#MapValue), but unable to do. And can you pls help me to write **where** and **orderBy** clause with cloud firestore in **API sting**

Comment: I recommend using the Try this API tool to validate your syntax. I used the [createDocument reference](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument) to validate an array field. It should help with a map field, too. For your query, use the [runQuery reference](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/runQuery). If you still get stuck, please start another question with an example.

Comment: Lots of thanks @JuanLaara. All the issues are fixed.

Comment: @AvinashMawle if the answer helped you and fixed all your problems then you should mark the answer as answered by clicking on the tick icon on the left side of the answer